# How to read and write the public and private key contained in "EVP_PKEY" in a readable way?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I would like to display the public and private key pair contained in "pkey", parameter of the EVP_PKEY_keygen function, in a human readable form,
that is, display an encoder key like this for example: 1GERarDJyXsANQqWGGdC3C26GA8K9yMQ7n.
Here is a piece of code:
generation of parameters and keys :

```
 EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, NULL);
if(ctx == NULL)
{
  std::cout << "error 1" << std::endl;
}
if(EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0)
{
    std::cout << "error 2" << std::endl;
}
if(EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid(ctx, NID_X9_62_prime256v1) <= 0)
{
    std::cout << "error 3" << std::endl;
}
if(EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0)
{
    std::cout << "error 4" << std::endl;
}
EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
```

My attempt 1 to display the private key contained in "ppkey"

```
EC_KEY *key;
if(!(key = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey)))
{
    std::cout << "error 5" << std::endl;
}
const BIGNUM *prvkey;
if(!(prvkey = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key)))
{
  std::cout << "error 6" << std::endl;
}
unsigned char *to = NULL;
if(!BN_bn2mpi(prvkey, to))
{
  std::cout << "error 7" << std::endl;
}
 std::cout << *prvkey <<std::endl;
```

here is the error display :

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'const BIGNUM' {aka 'const bignum_st'})|
```

how to display "*ppkey" in std :: cout and correct this error?

My attempt 2 to display the private key contained in "ppkey":

```
  BIO *bp = NULL;
  if(!EVP_PKEY_print_private(bp, pkey, 1, NULL))
   {
      std::cout << "error 5" << std::endl;
   }
       std::cout << bp <<std::endl;
```

there the error comes from the function because the condition if is to be respected.
How to define well the parameter 3 of the function because I think that the problem comes from that ?

Is there any other function, other method to display and write the keys?

Help me please

Comment: How to convert "* prvkey" or "* bp" so that it appears in a string. I need help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a NULL for the BIO (`bp`) parameter:

```
 BIO *bp = NULL;
 if(!EVP_PKEY_print_private(bp, pkey, 1, NULL))
```

This will cause `EVP_PKEY_print_private` to fail. The BIO represents the location where you want the key data to be printed, and must be non-NULL. If you just want to print to `stdout` then you can create it like this:

```
BIO *bp = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
```

Be sure to free the BIO up afterwards:

```
BIO_free(bp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works, but why does it also print the public key when it is a private key function?

Is it necessary to use the "EVP_PKEY_print_public ()" function to print the public key?

Comment: In OpenSSL private keys are always accompanied with public keys as a key pair. Obviously the opposite is not always true (you can have a public key without a private key). `EVP_PKEY_print_private` prints the whole key pair, `EVP_PKEY_print_public` prints just the public portion. I don't believe there is a function to print just the private portion of a keypair.